# "Plane" Model table not showing in the database and exception occurs while submitting the form in PlaneSchedule view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I am working on a Airline Management System on Visual Studio 2017. I am using code first entity framework approach. I have disabled the migrations in AirlineSytemContext.cs so that I can update or add any member later on in the Model Class. It has shown me the user class table in the local db as well as in the SQL server.

I have created a Plane Model as well but its not showing the Plane table in the db. I have created a PlaneSchedule View in the user "View" folder. When I submit the Plane Schedule form.
It shows me this exception.

> System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: 'An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.'   Invalid object name 'dbo.Planes'.

Plane Class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace AirlineticketSystem.Models
{
    public class Plane
    {
        [Key]
        public int Plane_id { get; set; }
        public string Plane_Name { get; set; }
        public string Plane_No { get; set; }
        public string Plane_BClass { get; set; }
        public string Plane_EClass { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Plane Schedule Form:

```
 <div class="formdiv">
     <form action="~/Planes/Planeform" method="post">
         @using (Html.BeginForm())
         {
          @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
          @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

 <div class="airform1">
     <label for="fname">Flight Number #</label>
     <input type="text" id="fname" name="Plane_Name" placeholder="Your name..">
 </div>


 <div class="airform1">
 <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
 <input type="text" id="lname" name="Plane_No " placeholder="Your last name..">
 </div>

 <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
 </form>

 </div>
```

Comment: EF6 or EF Core? In code first, you need to use one of the mechanisms that updates the database to match your code. Migrations is one method. Sounds like you turned that off so you could change your model? That is the very reason migrations exist. There are [automatic migrations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj554735(v=vs.113).aspx) that are useful during development. Another option (for EF6) is [database initializers](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/database-initialization-strategy-in-code-first.aspx) that update your database as the model changes.

Comment: I am using Entity Framework v4.5.2 .

Comment: That's a dotnet version. So it must be EF6. Use an initializer or migrations to update your database.

Comment: Okay sure. Thanks